# R - Understanding output of regexpr

Tags: r

Can you pls help in understanding output of regexpr? I am interested in text position that is 10 below. But it shows two values that is 10 and 4. How do I capture number 10 only.

Is this output a vector of numbers?

```
text<-"World is beautiful"
out<-regexpr("beau",text)
out
#[1] 10
#attr(,"match.length")
#[1] 4
#attr(,"useBytes")
#[1] TRUE
out[1]
#[1] 10
out[2]
#[1] NA
```

Answer (score 2):

`out` is a `length 1L` atomic vector with attributes...

```
str(out)
 atomic [1:1] 10
 - attr(*, "match.length")= int 4
 - attr(*, "useBytes")= logi TRUE
```

The value of `out` (try `c(out)` to drop the attributes) is `10` which describes the start position in the character vector for a match to your pattern. `attr( out , "match.length")` is
`[1] 4` which describes the length of the match.

Your `text` string is one element long, hence `out` is one element long. Try `regexpr("beau",rep(text,3))`.

Comment: @user2882768 you are welcome. If this or statquant's answer was satisfactory  for the question posed you should choose one to accept so this question is marked as answered. You can press the little green check mark next to your favourite answer if you feel like it! See the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website for more info. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

From the help page of `regexpr`. You can get it by typing `?regexpr` in R console.

> **regexpr** returns an integer vector of the same length as text giving
>   the starting position of the first match or -1 if there is none, with
>   attribute "match.length", an integer vector giving the length of the
>   matched text (or -1 for no match). The match positions and lengths are
>   in characters unless useBytes = TRUE is used, when they are in bytes.
>   If named capture is used there are further attributes "capture.start",
>   "capture.length" and "capture.names".